# What is the @ used for in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, mobx

I'm reading through the [MobX docs](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx) and I'm confused by the following code:

```
class Todo {
    id = Math.random();
    @observable title = "";
    @observable finished = false;
}

@observer
class TodoListView extends Component {
    render() {
        return <div>
            <ul>
                {this.props.todoList.todos.map(todo =>
                    <TodoView todo={todo} key={todo.id} />
                )}
            </ul>
            Tasks left: {this.props.todoList.unfinishedTodoCount}
        </div>
    }
}
```

What is the significance of the @ symbol?

Comment: it will probably be a decorator, but it's nothing official yet, afaik

Comment: https://medium.com/google-developers/exploring-es7-decorators-76ecb65fb841#.tdaza9alp

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice the comments before I posted.. Have an upvote.

Comment: About the first thing that is documented on the MobX Git page is ... how [decorators](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx) are used in MobX, and what they are ?

Comment: That's experimental syntax proposed for ES8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's called a decorator, you can read all about it here:

https://github.com/wycats/javascript-decorators

> A decorator is:
>
> - an expression that evaluates to a function that takes the target,
>     name, and decorator descriptor as arguments and optionally returns a
>     decorator descriptor to install on the target object